# Jasmine spies only detect calls on methods called on Node.js exports object

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to spy on dependencies in a Node.js module from within a Jasmine spec, and I'm encountering some weird behaviour.

Jasmine spies on a method that resides in an object exposed by the exports object in the module. When I call the spied-on method in the module using

```
exports.umap()
```

the spy detects it. But when I call it in the module using a variable name I assigned to the same method

```
var umap = exports.umap
umap()
```

the spy doesn't detect it.

This seems weird to me given that var umap refers to the same method as exports.umap. Anyone have any ideas why this is? Code below.

(The whole reason I'm doing this is that I want to stub my module's dependencies without the need to design the module as a class and use dependency injection.)

```
// mapper.js

exports.umap = require('underscore').map;

var umap = exports.umap;

function map () {
    return exports.umap([1,2,3], function(el) {console.log(el);return el * 2});

    // umap() goes unnoticed by the spy
    // return umap([1,2,3], function(el) {console.log(el);return el * 2});
}

exports.map = map;
```

.

```
// mapper_spec.js

var mapper = require ('../../lib/mapper');
var map = mapper.map;

describe('mapper', function() {
    describe('map', function() {
        it('calls umap', function() {
            var mapped;

            spyOn(mapper, 'umap').and.callThrough();

            mapped = mapper.map();

            expect(mapper.umap).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mapped).toEqual([2,4,6]);
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I'm still curious about this issue, however https://www.npmjs.org/package/proxyquire made my whole "spying-on-things-attached-to-export-object" strategy moot.